# Python - logging requests summary stats using locust

Tags: python-2.7, locust

I'm using locust

http://docs.locust.io/en/latest/index.html

to simulate a bunch of web users doing random site visits and file downloads.  The logging option is set by specifying

```
locust ... --logfile </path/to/log/file>...
```

But this only logs a subset of internal events and print statements in the code, it does not log the request stats which are printed out on the console (if you use the `--no-web` option) or the UI (if you don't specify the `--no-web` option).

How can you capture the request stats in the log file?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the log level.  From what I just read in the source it defaults to INFO

In your case I would type

```
locust ... --logfile </path/to/log/file> --loglevel DEBUG
```

Information from source:

```
help="Choose between DEBUG/INFO/WARNING/ERROR/CRITICAL. Default is INFO."
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me now that I've tried it.  My only other thought would be to look into extending the event hooks to print to the console.

Answer (score 1):

The stats you see on the console are a result of logging through the console_logger. See https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/master/locust/log.py#L50
You can add your custom FileHandler to the console_logger and get those stats in a file.

```
console_logger = logging.getLogger("console_logger")
fh = logging.FileHandler(filename="stats.log")
fh.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(message)s'))
console_logger.addHandler(fh)
```